# Excel formula to sum some values based on selections and weight percentage

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking for a way to make this example work:

[image: Excel snap]

The columns you see in the screenshot above are the columns L and M, the idea behind this little screenshot is that the user can make a selection in the second column ("Ja", "N.V.T.", etc), these selections should have different values. So lets say the "Ja" selection should count for 2,5 and any other selection should count for 1.

In the last cell of the screenshot (the one with the value: 2,5), a formula should count the amount of "Ja" selections, give them the correct value (2,5 if the weight percentage is 25%) and sum those values.

I'm currently using this formula (it also contains some other selections but for this example lets just focus on the "Ja" selection):

```
=(COUNTIF(M17:M20;"Ja")*10/M16)+(COUNTIF(M17:M20;"N.V.T.")*10/$M$16)+(COUNTIF(M17:M20;"Ja, maar..")*5/$M$16)
```

M17:M20 is the selection area and M16 is the row amount.

Is it possible to achieve this with just a formula or do I have to look for solutions elsewhere?

Comment: Something like: `=(COUNTIFS(M17:M20;"Ja";L17:L20;0,25)*2,5)+COUNTIF(M17:M20;"<>Ja")`

Comment: That works indeed, problem is that it only works if the weight percentage is 25%. The user is able to change that percentage so I need a dynamic solution, thanks for your answer though!

Comment: How about: `=(SUMIF(M17:M20;"Ja";L17:L20)*10)+COUNTIF(M17:M20;"<>Ja")`. Will the other values ("N.V.T." etc.) always be 1?

Comment: That's it!! Post it as an answer so I can mark this question solved please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comments:

```
=(SUMIF(M17:M20;"Ja";L17:L20)*10)+COUNTIF(M17:M20;"<>Ja")
```